# How can I send 140 byte in one SMS by sendDataMessage()

Tags: java, android, sms, smsmanager

I have read on different forums that we can send 160 (7 bit) characters and 140 (8 bit) bytes  in one SMS message.

I want to send 140 bytes of data in one SMS. 
I am can successfully send up to 133 bytes but not more than 133 bytes, Can any one guide Why I am unable to send 140 bytes of 8 bit data in one SMS through smsManager.sendDataMessage

Below is my code.

```
      int MAX_SMS_MESSAGE_LENGTH = 140;
      byte[] bArray = new byte [MAX_SMS_MESSAGE_LENGTH];
      for(int i=0;i<MAX_SMS_MESSAGE_LENGTH;i++)
      {
           bArray[i] = (byte)i;
      }
      PendingIntent sent = this.createPendingResult(SENT, new Intent(), PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
      String messageText = _message.getText().toString();

     SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
     smsManager.sendDataMessage(_phoneNumber.getText().toString(), null, SMS_PORT, bArray, sent, null);
```

Thanking in an Anticipation,

Regards,

AK

Comment: if my answer below helped you, please do accept it. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Part of the 140 bytes is reserved for the User Data Header (UDH) which is usually 7 bytes in size. More info can be found [here.](http://www.smsbullet.com.au/files/SMSB-HTTPS-current.pdf)