# Sending full length SMS using Android

Tags: java, android, mobile, sms

I am trying to send SMS messages using my application.

However, my messages are being cut off after 67 characters when sending through my application. I know the max length for an SMS is 160 characters and can send messages of this length using the native Android messaging app.

Here is my code:

```
String textToSend = "this is a string that is about 100 characters or so. It is being split up by android after 67 characters.";

SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
ArrayList<String> msgStringArray = sms.divideMessage(textToSend);

for(String s : msgStringArray){
    //this will say 67 and then the remainder 
    Log.d(TAG, "STRING LENGTH: " + s.length() + " " + s);
}

sms.sendMultipartTextMessage(selectedNumber, null, msgStringArray, null, null);
```

I am thinking that it is perhaps the encoding or something similar. I think that by default 16 bit encoding is being used instead of GSM but I haven't been able to find any examples of fixing this issues. A code example would be great!

I am using android 4.4 on an S3 to test this.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23180842/how-can-i-send-140-byte-in-one-sms-by-senddatamessage?rq=1

Comment: If you are sending multipart mime the mime headers are going to take up some of that space I would think

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. My hunch that it was the unicode encoding was correct.

Anyway, I came across this site: http://www.wrankl.de/JavaPC/SMSTools.html

There is a method called convertUnicode2GSM that I used to convert my String. Now it is sending the entire message in a single SMS instead of breaking after 67 characters.

Comment: Link is dead, could you include the method here?

Answer (score -1):

```
String smsNumber = "Insert number here"; //AIMS HELPLINE
String smsText = "Need to book an appointment with your hospital";
Uri uri = Uri.parse("smsto:" + smsNumber);
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, uri);
intent.putExtra("sms_body", smsText);
startActivity(intent);
```